# How to add captions for images in owl carousel 2-2.3.4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, owl-carousel

Is this code still working? I tried it but unfortunately, it didn't work...
I'm using OwlCarousel2-2.3.4 version. When I load the .JS code, and put the id #figcaption the figure didn't appear. I do not know why it isn't workin'...

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.theme.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.transitions.min.css" />

<figure id="currentImageWithCaption">
    <img src="https://malsup.github.io/images/p1.jpg" title="Title 1" alt="Title 1" width="200" height="150">
    <figcaption id="figcaption">Title 1</figcaption>
</figure>

<div class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="item">
        <img src="https://malsup.github.io/images/p1.jpg" title="Title 1" alt="Alt 1" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="https://malsup.github.io/images/p2.jpg" title="Title 2" alt="Alt 2" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="https://malsup.github.io/images/p3.jpg" title="Title 3" alt="Alt 3" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="https://malsup.github.io/images/p4.jpg" title="Title 4" alt="Alt 4" />
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<style>
figure img {
display: block;
width:100%;
height: auto;
}
.owl-wrapper-outer{
    display : none;
}
</style>

<script>
    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
        loop: true,
        items: 1,
        navigation: true,
        pagination: true,
        lazyLoad: true,
        afterMove: function(elem) {
            var current = this.currentItem;
            var currentImg = elem.find('.owl-item').eq(current).find('img');

            $('figure')
                .find('img')
                .attr('src', currentImg.attr('src'))
                .attr('alt', currentImg.attr('alt'))
                .attr('title', currentImg.attr('title'));
            $('#figcaption').text(currentImg.attr('title'));
        }
    });
</script>
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

You can use `translated.owl.carousel` event for that

> Here is a working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/3k4k23dn/2/)

```
owl.on('translated.owl.carousel', function(event) {
     var comment = $(this).find('.active').find('img').attr('alt');
    var title = $(this).find('.active').find('img').attr('title');
    if(comment) $('.image-caption').html('<h4>'+title+'</h4><p>'+comment+'</p>');
});
```

**UPDATE:**

> Slightly improved code and added functionality to update image caption
>   on carousel load.

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/3k4k23dn/2/)